# OpenCV converting one color to another

Tags: c++, opencv, colors

I have a greyscale image
I would like to convert all the white pixels (pure white - 255) to black (0)
only those colors, not all the greyscale
How can I do this?
Thank you!
Ron

Comment: Read the image into a matrix, loop through the matrix and check for 255 and 0 values and update them accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following.

1. Threshold your image using [`inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#cv2.inRange).

   ```
   Mat image;  // your original image
   Mat mask;
   void inRange(image, Scalar(255), Scalar(255), mask)
   ```

   The output `mask` will be a binary mask where its pixel is set to 255 if the corresponding pixel in `image` equals to 255 (that is if the pixel value is between 255 and 255, boundaries are inclusive).
2. Copy `black_image` (your desired substitute color) into your original `image` through `mask` using [`copyTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copy#void%20Mat%3a%3acopyTo%28OutputArray%20m%29%20const).

   ```
   Mat black_image(image.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(0));  // all zeros image
   black_image.copyTo(image, mask);
   ```

Comment: The upper bound of inRange is Exclusive :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use cvThreshold, see the last case "Threshold to Zero, Inverted" here:  http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

Set threshold value to 254, I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This would look like this:
`cv::threshold(input, output, 254, 255, cv::THRESH_TOZERO_INV);`