# How To Index And Modify An OpenCV Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

If I have an OpenCV cv::Mat, and I have a column of integers:

```
[1;2;3;1;2;3;1;2;3]
```

How can select a range of indices by value (ie 1), set those indices to a different value (ie 0), and keep the remaining values unmodified?

If this were MATLAB, I could very easily do:

```
A = [1;2;3;1;2;3;1;2;3];
A(A==1) = 0;
```

Resulting in:

```
[0;2;3;0;2;3;0;2;3]
```

Comment: this might help http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat

Comment: It seems you're asking to execute an operation on a `cv::Mat` given a predicate. I'm not sure if this is possible. Obviously one way to do it is just to loop through every pixel and check if your condition is true -- if so, then perform the operation you desire. It's more than one line, but that's all the one-liner would be doing anyway. You can't avoid looking at every pixel/entry in the matrix.

Comment: It is not as simple in OpenCV as it is in Matlab.  But you can use some built-in threshold functions of OpenCV.  [I've just answered a similar question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18212476/1121420). Also, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17094621/1121420)

Comment: I have my own function for that. In the function, I cast data attribute of the matrix for corresponding type of array and loop through the array to get what I want. Remember you are compensating convenience for performance by using c++ rather than matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not quite as succinct in OpenCV as it is in MATLAB, but it's close. The [`setTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#Mat&%20Mat::setTo%28InputArray%20value,%20InputArray%20mask%29) function is what you want. This takes advantage of the fact that some logical operations on `cv::Mat`, like `==` and `!=`, produce masks which can be passed to other functions:

```
uchar data[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3};
cv::Mat A(9, 1, CV_8UC1, data);
A.setTo(0, A == 1);
```

Which will give the result as expected:

```
[0; 2; 3; 0; 2; 3; 0; 2; 3]
```